# Sql Profiler Scan Started to execute a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Does SqlServer has to start a Scan to execute a stored procedure?

In Sql Profiler I can see this:

- RPC Starting ( exec sp_Edu3_SelectExamSession @ExamSessionId=N'AccessCode39361814' )
- Scan:Started
- Scan:Started
- Scan:Started
- RPC Completed ( exec sp_Edu3_SelectExamSession @ExamSessionId=N'AccessCode39361814' )

Can I somehow see what's happening in the Stored Procedure? Different queries are done in that SP, but they do not seem to appear in Sql Profiler (maybe I need to check some more events?)

The Scan:Started are probably scans by the queries in the sp? Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch profiler, there is a template where you can see stored proc line by line execution. It's something like "SQLProfilerTSQL_SPs" from memory.

The Scan event may be associated, it may not: it depends on the filters you have set.

Comment: which event class (`rpc:completed == 10`) would you recommend to inlude while analysing a trace file?  [This answer recommend to use 10 as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260660/819887) but in my case it seems that `43=SP:COMPLETED` is a better fit.