# Regarding Sql Profiling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

I want to know how to use the sql profiling tool for sql server 2008. for the anjlab sql profiler what filters should be set in order to get the exact query??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the anjlab profiler works in a similar fashion to the standard profiler, I'd suggest capturing rpc completed and sql batch completed events. Those are the two that will tell you the most about what queries are being called on the system. For detailed analysis, you could add statement completed events, but be prepared for managing large amounts of data.

Comment: Whenever I Start SQL profiler to track the queries some binary code is generated and I am unable to locate the exact query that is fired on database. So can you suggest me any setting that can be done in order to retrive the exact query?

Comment: Can sqlStmtcompleted and sql transactioncan be used? Also can we track the query execution time? E.g If there are 100 records to be deleted using an linq query then can we know the total time needed for the execution?

Comment: Can you tell me which reference file should be added in order to use deletebatch() and updatebatch() functions..